# Java Externalizable serialVersionUID

Tags: java, serialversionuid

If I implement Externalizable, will I need to specify serialVersionUID in that class for version compatibility?

In other words, does Java check serialVersionUID while deserializing Externalizable objects?

Comment: Can it even do that (if everything is externalized and nothing serialized)? Where to get the version number from?

Comment: Hmm. I guess it could since the object identity is still serialized.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Even through a class is Externalizable, one still has to add
a serialVersionUID member to the class to indicate even though
the interface to the class has changed, it is still compatible
as far as the serialized or externalized form of the class.

https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=4094702

Comment: According to Hazelcast, in Externalizable it is not needed: https://docs.hazelcast.com/imdg/4.2/serialization/implementing-java-serializable#implementing-java-externalizable